# what is the residue of $\sin(z^2)/z^7$

Tags: complex-analysis

what is the residue of $$\frac{\sin(z^2)}{z^7} \text{ at } z=0.$$ I'm finding trouble at the limit part at the end.
I am using  the formula:
$$\operatorname{res}(f,z_0)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} ((z-z_0)^n f(z))$$

Comment: Hint: expand $\sin w$ into a power series in $w$, substitute $w=z^2$ and divide by $z^7$. Now look at the coefficient of $z^{-1}$.

Comment: what about the 1/6!

Comment: the answer they are showing is -1/6

Comment: Hi @Karthik! I think the discrepancy comes from the fact that we should be expanding the power series of $\sin \left(z^2\right)$ rather than $\sin z$ (plug in $z^2$ into the power series instead of $z$).

Comment: sir, I plugged in the z^2 into the power series. I am getting confused at the limit part and I am not understanding what happens to 1/6!

Comment: $$
\sin w = w - \frac{{w^3 }}{{3!}} + \frac{{w^5 }}{{5!}} -  \cdots  \Rightarrow \sin (z^2 ) = z^2  - \frac{{z^6 }}{{3!}} + \frac{{z^{10} }}{{5!}} -  \cdots \\ \Rightarrow \frac{{\sin (z^2 )}}{{z^7 }} = \frac{1}{{z^5 }} - \frac{1}{{3!}}\frac{1}{z} + \frac{{z^3 }}{{5!}} -  \cdots 
$$ Note $-\frac{1}{3!}=-\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: @Gary! we have to take the limit to this equation right?

Comment: Do you know that the residue of a function at a point $z_0$ is the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ in the Laurent series of the function about $z_0$? What limit are you talking about? Just pick the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$, and that is the residue.

Comment: in our class notes they have taken the limit of the power series and just directly wote the answer thats why i got confused.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that
$$\sin(z)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n} z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}+\cdots$$
Which also means that
$$\sin(z^2)=z^2-\frac{z^6}{3!}+\frac{z^{10}}{5!}+\cdots$$
And thus
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z^7}\sin{(z^2)}&=\frac{1}{z^7}\left( z^2-\frac{z^6}{3!}+\frac{z^{10}}{5!}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{z^5}-\frac{1}{3!}\frac{1}{z}+\cdots
\end{align}
And so in the Laurent series expansion, the coefficient of the $1/z$ term is the residue at $z=0$. And thus
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=0}\left( \frac{\sin(z^2)}{z^7}\right)=-\frac{1}{3!}=-\frac{1}{6}$$